# How to calculate the time passed in an array of time slots in PHP

Tags: php

Have time slots which are in ascending order:

```
// 1st slot
$timeslot[] = '07:00-08:00';
// total = 1 hr

// 2nd slot
$timeslot[] = '07:15-07:30'; // not considered since it lies between the first slot ie 7 to 8
// total = 1 hr

// 3rd slot
$timeslot[] = '07:30-08:30'; // 1 hr of the first slot + remaining 30 minutes of this slot = 1:30 hrs
// total = 1:30 hrs

// 4rth slot
$timeslot[] = '10:45-11:45'; // 1:30 hrs + 1 hr
// total = 2:30 hrs
```

so far i have tried like this but no hope; what i'm trying to get is the time passed between the slots. for example we have two time slots 07:00-08:00 and 07:30-08:30, the time travelled in these two time slot is 1:30 hours. so something like this i'm calculating. My code goes like this:-

```
function addtimespend($dumparray = '', $i, $diff)
{
    $arr1 = explode("-", $dumparray[0]);
    if (isset($dumparray[$i])) {
        $arr2 = explode("-", $dumparray[$i]);

        if (strtotime($arr2[1]) > strtotime($arr1[1]) && strtotime($arr2[0]) < strtotime($arr1[1])) {
            $diff = $diff + (strtotime($arr2[1]) - strtotime($arr1[1]));

            return $diff;

        } else {
            $diff = $diff + (strtotime($arr1[1]) - strtotime($arr1[0]));
        }

        $i++;

        return addtimespend($dumparray, $i, $diff);
    } else {
        $diff = $diff + (strtotime($arr1[1]) - strtotime($arr1[0]));
        return $diff;

    }
}

$flag = $diff = 0;
$diff = addtimespend($event, 1, 0);
function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%02d:%02d')
{
    if ($time < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $hours   = floor($time / 60);
    $minutes = ($time % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}

echo convertToHoursMins($diff / 60, '%02d hours %02d minutes');
```

Comment: This looks like a good sample exercise to learn test driven development. And to make it easier, you could first filter out those slots covered by others (like the second in the example) and then sum up

Comment: Will the timeslots always be in sorted order?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, the start time is sorted in ascending order .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$timeslot = [];
$timeslot[] = '07:00-08:00';
$timeslot[] = '07:15-07:30';
$timeslot[] = '07:30-08:30'; 
$timeslot[] = '10:45-11:45';

$min_time = -1;
$max_time = -1;
$total_minutes = 0;

foreach($timeslot as $slot){
    list($start_time,$end_time) = explode("-",$slot);

    $start_time = explode(":",$start_time);
    $start_time = intval($start_time[0]) * 60 + intval($start_time[1]); // converting to minutes
    $end_time = explode(":",$end_time);
    $end_time = intval($end_time[0]) * 60 + intval($end_time[1]);// converting to minutes


    if($min_time == -1){// or max time for that matter (just basic initialization of these 2 variables)
        $min_time = $start_time;
        $max_time = $end_time;
        $total_minutes += $max_time - $min_time;
    }else{
        if($start_time >= $max_time) $total_minutes += $end_time - $start_time;
        else if($start_time < $max_time && $end_time > $max_time) $total_minutes += $end_time - $max_time;

        $min_time = min($min_time,$start_time);
        $max_time = max($max_time,$end_time);
    } 
}

echo intval($total_minutes / 60),":",($total_minutes % 60)," hrs";
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/nvjDq

**Algorithm:**

- *Since your data is sorted according to start times*, we can just keep track of min and max times of timeslots.
- For simplicity, we can convert the timeslot in  minutes.
- We add to our total only under these 2 conditions:

  - If the current slot collides with the time range we maintain.
  - If the current slot is completely out of bounds of the current time range.
- In the end, we print the answer in hours format.

Answer (score 1):

i made a little script to calculate your timeslots, which works also fine with UNSORTED timeslots:

```
<?php

$timeslots = [];

// 2nd slot
$timeslots[] = '07:00-08:00'; // not considered since it lies between the first slot ie 7 to 8 // total = 1 hr
$timeslots[] = '07:15-08:00'; // 1st slot
$timeslots[] = '07:30-08:00'; // 1st slot
$timeslots[] = '07:30-08:30'; // 3rd slot
$timeslots[] = '07:45-08:45'; // 1 hr of the first slot + remaining 30 minutes of this slot = 1:30 hrs // total = 1:30 hrs // remove duplicate one's
// // 4rth slot
$timeslots[] = '10:45-11:45';

$test = new test;

foreach ($timeslots as $timeslot) {
    $test->checkInBetween($timeslot);
}

$totalDiff = 0;

foreach ($test->sequences as $key => $sequence) {
    $sequenceDifference = strtotime($sequence['latestEnd']) - strtotime($sequence['earliestStart']);
    $totalDiff          += $sequenceDifference;
}


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($totalDiff);
die();

class test {

    public $sequences = [
        0   => [
            'earliestStart' => '',
            'latestEnd'     => '',
        ],
    ];

    public function checkInBetween($timeslot) {
        $exploded           = explode('-', $timeslot);
        $isEarliest         = false;
        $isLatest           = false;
        $isBetweenFirst     = false;
        $isBetweenSecond    = false;
        $sequenceFound      = false;

        foreach ($this->sequences as $key => $sequence) {

            // Check if the first number is the earliest
            if (($exploded[0] < $sequence['earliestStart'])) {
                $isEarliest = true;
            }

            // Check if the last number is the latest
            if (($exploded[1] > $sequence['latestEnd'])) {
                $isLatest = true;
            }

            if ($exploded[0] > $sequence['earliestStart'] && $exploded[0] < $sequence['latestEnd']) {
                $isEarliest = false;
                $isBetweenFirst = true;
            }

            if ($exploded[1] > $sequence['earliestStart'] && $exploded[1] < $sequence['latestEnd']) {
                $isLatest = false;
                $isBetweenSecond = true;
            }

            if (($isEarliest && $isLatest) || ($isEarliest && $isBetweenSecond)) {
                $this->sequences[$key]['earliestStart'] = $exploded[0];
                $sequenceFound = true;
            }

            if (($isEarliest && $isLatest) || ($isLatest && $isBetweenFirst)) {
                $this->sequences[$key]['latestEnd'] = $exploded[1];
                $sequenceFound = true;
            }

        }

        if (!$sequenceFound) {
            $this->sequences[] = [
                'earliestStart' => $exploded[0],
                'latestEnd'     => $exploded[1],
            ];
        }
    }

}
```

Feel free to ask questions. Please mind that the output (totalDiff) contains seconds!

A few words to the script:
The script checks every value inside the timeslots array and tries to merge it into a sequence if the starting time is in between an existing sequence or  the ending time is in between an existing sequence. If one of those conditions are met, the sequence is updated with the new value.
If none of those conditions are met, the script adds a new sequence, as the current values are not matching any existing conditions.

After iterating every value inside the timeslot, the sequences will be calculated in terms of difference in seconds, which will be added to the totalDiff.

Comment: let me test this

Comment: // 2nd slot
$timeslots[] = '07:00-08:00'; // not considered since it lies between the first slot ie 7 to 8
// total = 1 hr
$timeslots[] = '07:15-08:00';

// 1st slot
$timeslots[] = '07:30-08:30';

// 3rd slot
$timeslots[] = '07:45-08:45'; // 1 hr of the first slot + remaining 30 minutes of this slot = 1:30 hrs
// total = 1:30 hrs

// remove duplicate one's

// 4rth slot
$timeslots[] = '10:45-11:45'; gives wrong results

Comment: @rahul can you give me the detailed problem?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't describe anything more than that in the question

Comment: @rahul, no worries. i updated the script, it should work, i found the bug. Thanks for letting me know! Please do not hesitate, if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if the time slots are shorted by their start time in ascending order.

```
<?php
$timeslots[] = '07:00-08:00';
$timeslots[] = '07:15-07:30';
$timeslots[] = '07:30-08:30';
$timeslots[] = '10:45-11:45'; 
$slots=array();
foreach($timeslots as $timeslot){
    $timeslot=explode("-",$timeslot);
    $start=toMinutes($timeslot[0]);
    $end=toMinutes($timeslot[1]);
    $slots[]=["start"=>$start,"end"=>$end];
    $starts[]=$start;
    $ends[]=$end;
}

function toMinutes($time){
    $arr= explode(":",$time);
    return ($arr[0] * 60) + $arr[1];
}
function toTime($minutes){
    return floor($minutes / 60) .":". $minutes % 60;
}
function totalGapMinutes($slots){
    $count=count($slots);
    $i=0;
    $gap=0;
    for($i; $i<$count-1; $i++){
        if($slots[$i]['end']<$slots[$i+1]['start']){
            $gap+=$slots[$i+1]['start']-$slots[$i]['end'];
        }

    }
    return $gap;
}
var_dump(toTime(max($ends)-min($starts) - totalGapMinutes($slots)));
```